# Messagin system and APNS

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to create an iphone app for messaging system .If one user send a message to other one , device need to frequently check with server if there is a message,It use more battery.

Is it possible to use Apple Push notification system in my project to send messages between users from server?

Help is highly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. In fact, since you can only poll a server on iOS when the app is open on the user's device, I don't think you have much of a choice. The basic set-up would be to enable APNS in your app and follow this kind of flow :

1. Register the devices' push tokens upon launch (let's say User A
   and User B)
2. When User A messages User B, User B may or may not
   have the app opened. User A's message should go through your web
   service which sends a push notification to User B. If User B has the
   app open, the app should intercept the notification and deal with
   whatever information it contains - maybe it contains the actual
   message, maybe it contains just a signal that his device should
   check for new messages. If User B does not have the app open, the
   notification should appear on screen with some basic text informing
   him that User A has sent a message.